# Find duplicate records and give result in concat string

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have 2 tables where some of the records will be identical (except for the id)

Table A:

```
id, numA, codeA
6, 34, aa 
7, 34, bb 
8, 567, bc
```

Table B

```
id, numB, codeB 
1, 34, aa 
2, 34, bb 
3, 567, bc
```

I need to run a query on Table B which will check if given combination of num and code exists in Table A and will give the result in such format:

```
num, concat code
34, (aa,bb) 
567, (bc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the two tables and use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT  a.NumA, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.codeB)
FROM    table1 A
        INNER JOIN table2 b
          on a.numA = b.numB
GROUP BY a.NumA
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87ad9/2)

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! It was a "distinct" that I was missing in group_concat. Now it's quite obvious, but yesterday it wasn't :)